# Show div only on Homepage using only JS & CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to only show this div on the homepage, im using a issue tracking software online which allows customization. But i can only use JS and CSS. How can i set the div to only show on example.com/homepage and not on any other page.

----------------HERE IS THE CODE--------------
JS:

```
$('#mainArea')
    .before(
        '<div id="vmenu"><table width=900><tr><td width=50% rowspan=2>Welcome to the Software Partner Portal. Click on “Case status” to see all your open cases, or “New case” to submit a new one.<br><br>The “Wiki” option is where you can find searchable reference material on a variety of topics from product documentation to release notes and even tips on IT issues.<br><br>If you need any help please contact us at <a href="mailto:partners@example.com">partners@example.com</a> or 514.335.5525.</td></tr></table></div>'
    );
$('a.navlink[href*="default.asp?pre=preLogOff"]')
    .attr('href', 'http://www.example.com/login.php')
$("table.biglist")
    .find("tr")
    .each(function() {
        $(this)
            .find("td:contains('Closed')")
            .each(function() {
                $(this)
                    .parent()
                    .hide();
            });
    });
```

css:

```
#mainArea, mainAreaContinued{
}
#idLinkToFogCreek {
    display:none;
}
table#mainArea {
    display:none;
}
#vmenu {
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #E0E9F1;
    border: 2px solid #B1C9DD;
    font-family: 'Cambria',Georgia,'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
}
#vmenu ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:5px;
}
#vmenu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
}
#vmenu h4 {
    color:black;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #f0f0f0;
    margin:0;
}
#vmenu a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#vmenu li {
    margin-bottom:2px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this condition:

```
if (location.href.indexOf('homepage') !== -1) {
    //Show the div
}
```

Comment: Would i wrap that around my current JS? im not fluent in js can you show me were to add it

Comment: yes, where "//Show the div" is, you should add your code that displays the div.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is reading in the `location.href` or `location.pathname` of the url (whatever that may be in your application) and then just run a function to assign a class to the `<body>` and you can style against that.